# Android. Получение ссылки на сервис во фрагменте и смена ориентации экрана?

Tags: android

Есть Activity, в нем происходит запуск сервиса и привязка (bind). В итоге в onServiceConnected() получаю ссылку на сервис. Эта ссылка используется во фрагментах. 
Суть проблемы: при смене ориентации обнуляется ссылка на сервис.
Какие здесь могут быть способы решения? Биндить в каждом фрагменте?

Comment: Это не ссылка обнуляется, это активность уничтожается и создается новая. Поэтому достаточно при создании подключаться к сервису

Answer (score 1, accepted):

каждый фрагмент пусть коннектится/биндится к сервису самостоятельно

Comment: Совершенно верно, я даже больше скажу, чем меньше работы делается в активности, тем лучше. Фрагменты должны быть как можно более самостоятельными, их основной смысл именно в этом и состоит.